# Triangle design/texture for Pythagorean theorem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I found a very nice and intuitive figure for a proof of the Pythagorean theorem:

[image]

My main question is how to get that "look" for the triangles--I really like how the colors complement each other and have an interesting gradient it seems. I would like to reproduce exactly this figure using TikZ, but I do not know much TikZ at all.

I imagine drawing the triangles would only require a cursory look through the TikZ/PGF manual, but I was wondering if someone knowledgeable here knew how to produce the look/feel of the figure above (also the labeling of the sides of the triangles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possibility where `scope` environment with `shift` and `rotate` options are used to place the small triangles

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

\begin{scope}
\draw[gray,shade, top color=white,bottom color =blue!30] (0,0) --
 node[black,left,pos=0.5]{3} +(0,3) --node[black,right,pos=0.4]{5} +(4,0)--
 node[black,below,pos=0.5]{4} cycle;
\end{scope}
\node at (4.5,1.5){$\boldsymbol =$};
\begin{scope}[shift={(6cm,0.05cm)}]
\path[name path=circle] (0,0)  circle(2.5cm);
\path[name path=line] (0,3)--(4,0);
\path [name intersections={of = circle and line}];
\draw[gray,shade, top color=white,bottom color =green!30] (0:0) --
 node[black,left,pos=0.5]{3}+(0,3) -- +($(intersection-1)!0.5!(intersection-2)$)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6.1cm]
\path[name path=circle] (0,0)  circle(2.5cm);
\path[name path=line] (0,3)--(4,0);
\path [name intersections={of = circle and line}];
\draw[gray,shade, left color=white,right color =red!50] (0:0) --
node[black,below,pos=0.5]{4}+(4,0) -- +($(intersection-1)!0.5!(intersection-2)$)--
node[black,above right,pos=0]{5}cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{scope}
\draw[gray,shade, top color=white,bottom color =blue!30] (0,0) --
 node[black,left,pos=0.5]{} +(0,3) --node[black,right,pos=0.4]{5} +(4,0)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\node at (4.5,1.5){$\boldsymbol =$};
\begin{scope}[shift={(6.1cm,2.5)},rotate=143,yscale=1,xscale=-1]
\path[name path=circle] (0,0)  circle(2.5cm);
\path[name path=line] (0,3)--(4,0);
\path [name intersections={of = circle and line}];
\draw[gray,shade, top color=white,bottom color =red!50] (0:0) --
node[black,right,pos=0.4]{4}+(4,0) -- +($(intersection-1)!0.5!(intersection-2)$)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\node at (10,1.5){$\boldsymbol +$};
\begin{scope}[shift={(14cm,0.1cm)},rotate=53,yscale=1,xscale=-1]
\path[name path=circle] (0,0)  circle(2.5cm);
\path[name path=line] (0,3)--(4,0);
\path [name intersections={of = circle and line}];
\draw[gray,shade, top color=white,bottom color =green!20] (0:0) --
node[black,right,pos=0.6]{3}+(0,3) -- +($(intersection-1)!0.5!(intersection-2)$)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```